# where to define a global logger in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i would like to use a global logger in a custom file in rails,
where is the best place to define such a thing ?

I want to define it only once and then use it all around ..

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400831/create-a-custom-rails-logger

but simply put, to set the rails logger globally use:

```
Rails.logger =
```

or you can put it into an environment file, e.g. in config/environments/development.rb

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.logger = ...
end
```