# how to set up custom logger in rails 3.2 controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

Hi I am a newbie in rails,I want to implement a logger in such a manner that I can write the time taken by a specific api call when it is called.This is implemented in various pages.The front end language I am using in this is angularjs.

The below is the snippet in the controller called as appi controller:-

```
if get_params.has_key?('mode')
      if @userparams.has_key?(get_params[:mode])
        local_params = @userparams[get_params[:mode]]

        get_params.each do |key, value|
          local_params[key] = get_params[key]
        end

        has_param = true
      end
    end

    call = local_params["call"]
    local_params.delete(:call)

    js = "{}"
    if has_param

      js = Net::HTTP.get('services.example.com', "/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/"+ call +"?".concat(local_params.collect { |k,v| "#{k}=#{CGI::escape(v.to_s)}" }.join('&')))

    end
```

I want to print the time take by the api call(I am getting the name of api in 'call').

This is what I am getting in the console is the following:-

```
Started GET "/appi/user?context=custid%3D1%3Bmsisdn%3D222%3Bheadendid%3D2645%3Bapplicationname%3Dwebsite&mode=myWatchlist&noCache=1405430135225&pageno=1&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&userid=196878" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-15 18:45:35 +0530
Processing by AppiController#user as JSON
  Parameters: {"context"=>"custid=1;msisdn=222;headendid=2645;applicationname=website", "mode"=>"myWatchlist", "noCache"=>"1405430135225", "pageno"=>"1", "responseformat"=>"json", "responselanguage"=>"English", "userid"=>"196878"}
Completed 200 OK in 2273ms (Views: 0.6ms)
```

I want to display only the api for eg:-above call in the log.

What do I do in the following case.
Thanks

Comment: This has been [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233401/custom-logger-in-rails-3) and [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707300/rails-custom-logger-writes-to-log-sporadically) [countless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400831/create-a-custom-rails-logger) times.

Comment: @tirdadc..I am a bit confused.Can you please suggest how to implement the above